# Can this angular OR expression be shortened?

Tags: angularjs

Is there an easy way to shorten this expression?

```
     <li ng-if="viewingContext.name == 'Business A' || viewingContext.name == 'Business B'" ui-sref-active="active">
       <a ui-sref="app.page1">
         <span>Page 1</span>
       </a>
     </li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with what you have? you could create a function but the same logic would just be moved elsewhere...

Comment: Your logic is fine.  But I would recommend moving it to a controller so that it can be easily tested.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!!!! Send that bad boy to your controller:

```
<li ng-if="shouldDisplayBasedOnViewingContext()" ui-sref-active="active">
   <a ui-sref="app.page1">
     <span>Page 1</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.shouldDisplayBasedOnViewingContext() = function shouldDisplayBasedOnViewingContextFn() {
   return $scope.viewingContext.name == 'Business A' || $scope.viewingContext.name == 'Business B'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I second moving the logic to a controller.

Additionally, if you might end up with more than two items to check against, you could make a list of them and check for inclusion :

```
['Business A', 'Business B'].includes(input)      // only works in ES6
['Business A', 'Business B'].indexOf(input) != -1 // works in ES5
```